# Import all columns from CSV as character?

Tags: sas

Simple question.

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= braw.address
DATAFILE= "&path.\address_data.csv"
DBMS=csv REPLACE;
GETNAMES=YES;

RUN;
```

This statement will create the dataset columns as character *or* numeric depending on the values, which is smart, but not what I want.

I want to import them all as character, to make for easier regex evaluation.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why not just keep them natively typed, then cast them to char at the point you do your regex evaluation?

Comment: @sasfrog - Well ok, another problem is that a credit card value like 0000123412341234 is going to evaluate to 123412341234 if it's numeric, which isn't what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to write a SAS macro to read all the columns as character, you could try a "cheat".  Manually edit the file and duplicate the first row (the one containing column headers.  Since those will most likely all be character strings, SAS should import all the columns as character.

Of course, a macro to do this would not be that difficult. You can try something like this:

```
%macro readme(dsn,fn);
/* Macro to read all columns of a CSV as character */
/* Parameters:                                     */
/*   DSN - The name of the SAS data set to create  */
/*   FN  - The external file to read (quoted)      */
/* Example:                                        */
/*    %readme(want, 'c:\temp\tempfile.csv');       */
data _null_;
  infile &fn;
  input;
  i = 1;
  length headers inputstr $200;
  headers = compress(_infile_,"'");
  newvar = scan(headers,1,',');
  do until (newvar = ' ');
     inputstr = trim(inputstr) || ' ' || trim(newvar) || ' $';
     i + 1;
     newvar = scan(headers,i,',');
     end;
  call symput('inputstr',inputstr);
  stop;
run;

data &dsn;
  infile &fn firstobs=2 dsd dlm=',' truncover;
  input &inputstr.;
run;
%mend;
%readme(want, 'c:\temp\tempfile.csv');
```

Answer (score 3):

I would generally just write my own input statement for the CSV, then you can make them whatever you want.

IE:

```
data braw.address;
infile "&path.\address_data.csv" dlm=',' dsd missover;
input
 field1 $
 field2 $
....
;
run;
```

You can use the log from the PROC IMPORT to generate this the first time and just edit it to contain $ for each variable.

Comment: The problem I have with this appraoch is that I then need to go through an define them for each field. 

I could write some macros to make that a bit easier.

Comment: I don't think a macro is needed for this.  Use the PROC IMPORT code and modify it to add the $.  Use PROC PRINTTO to send your log to a file, then PROC IMPORT the file (Accepting the numerics for now), then read in the log generated - you can then add $ to the generated code and re-run it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my macro to read dlm file with all vars as char:

```
%MACRO ImportText(file,dsn,dlm);

* Read data use proc import to get variable name and length;
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="&file" OUT=temp DBMS=dlm REPLACE;
     DELIMITER = &dlm;
     GETNAMES = YES;
     GUESSINGROWS = 32767;
RUN;

* Put variable names into macro variable;
PROC CONTENTS DATA=temp out=vars NOPRINT; RUN;
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    SELECT CATT(name,' : $',length,'.') INTO :vars SEPARATED BY ' ' FROM vars ORDER BY varnum;
QUIT; 

* Read real data;
DATA &dsn;
    INFILE "&file" DELIMITER=&dlm MISSOVER DSD FIRSTOBS=2 LRECL=32767;
    INPUT &vars;
RUN;

%MEND;
```

Comment: This will miss value. for example, original file has a value `"001000011502"`, it will only import `00100001`

Comment: Why is that? I never had this problem.