# Import all columns from CSV as character? in many variables csv data

Tags: csv, macros, sas

I found an answer for this in the following url.

[Import all columns from CSV as character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614369/import-all-columns-from-csv-as-character)

However, for my data, this macro only import 43 variables, which should be 4126 variables.

I thought this problem might come from the macro syntax where

do until (newvar = ' ');

However, I am not capable of fixing this.

Can some teach me how to fix it.

My csv data could be download as follow dropbox link.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m01iaqkg5s0tkl2/1771020.csv?dl=0

```
%macro readme(dsn,fn);
/* Macro to read all columns of a CSV as character */
/* Parameters:                                     */
/*   DSN - The name of the SAS data set to create  */
/*   FN  - The external file to read (quoted)      */
/* Example:                                        */
/*    %readme(want, 'c:\temp\tempfile.csv');       */
data _null_;
  infile &fn;
  input;
  i = 1;
  length headers inputstr $200;
  headers = compress(_infile_,"'");
  newvar = scan(headers,1,',');
  do until (newvar = ' ');
     inputstr = trim(inputstr) || ' ' || trim(newvar) || ' $';
     i + 1;
     newvar = scan(headers,i,',');
     end;
  call symput('inputstr',inputstr);
  stop;
run;

data &dsn;
  infile &fn firstobs=2 dsd dlm=',' truncover;
  input &inputstr.;
run;
%mend;
%readme(want, 'c:\temp\tempfile.csv');
```

Comment: I prefer not to use proc import procedure. Because of in my case that only a few observation and too many variables, proc import procedure would take too much time to identify variables and truncate the variable name after 3000 variables.

Answer (score 1):

With 3000 variables your main problem is probably that the line length is too long.  Make sure to use the LRECL option on the INFILE statement.

You could just ignore the variable names.

```
data want ;
  infile "myfile" dsd firstobs=2 truncover lrecl=1000000 ;
  length var1-var3000 $200 ;
  input var1-var3000;
run;
```

Or you could read the names from the first line and use them to generate code. You probably cannot use a macro variable since they are limited to 65K characters.  It would be easier to generate a LENGTH statement from the names.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  file code ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'LENGTH';
  if eof then put ' $200 ;';
  infile "myfile" dsd obs=1 lrecl=1000000 end=eof;
  length name $32 ;
  input name @@ ;
  put ' ' name ;
run;
```

Then you can use that LENGTH statement in a step that creates the table.

```
data want ;
  infile "myfile" dsd firstobs=2 truncover lrecl=1000000 ;
%include code / source2 ;
  input (_all_) (+0) ;
run;
```

Also make sure to set the COMPRESS option since you will probably be creating variables that are much longer than they need to be.  You can set the system option.

```
options compress=yes;
```

Or use a dataset option.

```
data want (compress=yes);
```

If the column headings are not actually variable names then use them as labels instead.  You could change the code generation step as below to generate both LENGTH and LABEL statements to name the variables using generic names VAR1, VAR2,... .

```
data _null_;
  file code ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'LABEL';
  if eof then put ';' / 'LENGTH VAR1-VAR' N ' $200 ;';
  infile "myfile" dsd obs=1 lrecl=1000000 end=eof;
  length label $256 ;
  input label @@ ;
  N+1;
  put ' VAR' N '=' label :$quote. ;
run;
```

Comment: I run the second syntax u gave.

filename code temp; 

but I cost me ten mins and not finished. 

so I terminated it. 

I looks that the method you provide to read the name from csv data cost too much time. 

could we have a better way?

Comment: The problem was the TRUNCOVER option. I have removed it. The OBS=1 will make it only read one line so it will not take very long (if it doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop!).

Comment: I found some error as following when I used this syntax.
      180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

It looks like that some variables name had problems when we imported them.

Comment: Then don't use the names.  Convert them to labels instead if you want.  You could also try to use VALIDVARNAME=ANY system option and the NVALID and NLITERAL functions in the code that generates the names. But if the values are longer than 32 characters or not unique then you will still have trouble.